# how this matrix multiplication work in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused because my analytic solution is different from my python code's result, here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[2, 3],
              [3, -2]])

lam = 1.5
A[1,1:2] = A[1,1:2] - lam*A[0,1:2] # How this matrix work ?
print(A)
```

and I got the answer:

```
A = [[2, 3],
     [3, -6]]
```

but in my writing analytic solution, it should be

```
A = [[2, 3],
     [3, -6.5]]
```

Comment: Are you asking how indexing works for numpy arrays?

Comment: I'm sorry i got typo in my actual code i write in lowercase

Comment: Why not `print(A[1,1:2] - lam*A[0,1:2])`? Are you not curious at all?

Comment: While declaring A numpy array, make it as float.For example, A = A.astype(np.float32) . Then do the computation. Your analytical solution is correct. As it is, numpy array A is of uint8. So it converts 6.5 into 6 after computation. I guess this is implicit typecasting

Comment: @MadPhysicist `I don't think Facebook is a valid identifier` what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Yatin. Referring to a previous edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your computation is inefficient and uses questionable indexing, it is valid, and mathematically the answer should be 6.5.

The discrepancy is because of how you initialize the array:

```
A = np.array([[2, 3], [3, -2]])
```

Since all the objects here are `int`s, the array has a `dtype` of `np.int_`. Integers truncate, so you see a result of 6.

To fix this, make at least the first element into a `float`:

```
A = np.array([[2., 3], [3, -2]])
```

Notice the dot after the `2.`. That's all it takes.